# Can't save data by index into mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

This code gets data from mysql database and perform some arithmetic operation on it then updates the 'branch_price' columns in the database. I would like to batch update the column

```
$this->db->select('bprice');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->limit(20);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

$data = array();

foreach($query as $key => $value){

    $data = array(
        'branch_price' => (float)$value['bprice'][$key] + ((float)$value['bprice'][$key] * 0.30)
    );

}

return $this->db->update_batch('items',$data);
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$data` each time through the loop. You should be pushing onto the array, not replacing it.

Comment: And `$data` is missing the index column.

Comment: you could better resolve this with an MySQL query, check: [MySQL Arithmetic Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

`$data` should be a 2-dimensional array, so you need to push each array onto it in the loop. And the nested arrays need the index of the row to update.

When you call `update_batch()` you have to specify which column to use in the `WHERE` clause.

You don't need `[$key]`. `$value` is already the array element indexed by that key.

```
foreach($query as $value){
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $value['id'],
        'branch_price' => (float)$value['bprice'] * 1.30
    );
}

return $this->db->update_batch('items',$data, 'id');
```

Replace `id` with the actual name of the primary key of the table.

You can also have MySQL perform the calculation while updating instead of doing separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries.

```
$this->db->set('branch_price', 'branch_price * 1.30', false);
$this->db->update('items');
```

The `false` argument disables escaping, so the formula will be used directly.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar. It really worked for me as I was overwriting the $data variable always.